# Realloc или связный список malloc'ов?

Tags: c, память

Пишу реализацию "вечного буфера", возник вопрос о том какая операция дороже `malloc` или `realloc`.

Первый вариант реализации:

1. При инициализации буфера выделяется память с помощью `malloc`, под то что в него хотят записать:
   `buff* a = buff_init("data", 4)`, как то так.
2. При записи с помощью `realloc` расширять выделенный буфер и записывать данные.

Второй вариант реализации:

1. При инициализации создается блок допустим размером в 1кб, и указатель на следующий блок (по умолчанию `NULL`).
2. Если блок заполняется, то выделяется новый, обновляя указатели в предыдущем (без использования `realloc`)

Отсюда вытекает ряд вопросов, помогите пожалуйста:

1. На сколько затратно использовать операцию `realloc` по сравнению с `malloc`?
2. Как работает `realloc`?
3. Как `free` определяет конец памяти которую нужно освободить?
4. Какой оптимальный размер блока выбрать для 2 варианта реализации?
5. Как реализован класс `string` в C++, он же тоже своего рода вечный буфер?

Что почитать об этом? Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `malloc` менее затратен, чем `realloc`, так как в случае `malloc` находит и выбирает участок свободной памяти необходимого размера, при этом расположение данного участка не так важно.
2. При использовании `realloc`, выполняется операция `malloc`, а затем копируется выделенная ранее часть байт.
3. `malloc` при выделении памяти записывает метаинформацию, это уже вопросы управления памятью. Вообще данные функции всего лишь обёртки для вызова операций ядра ОС.
4. Зависит от данных, размер может быть динамическим. Вообще посмотрите в сторону структур данных, в данном случае вы почти описали список.
5. Вообще это массив символов. Можно найти [реализации](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.2/libstdc++/api/a01075_source.html).

Comment: Спасибо, еще один вопрос, `calloc` это тот же `malloc` который перемножает свои входы, как он работает?

Comment: перемножает? Он просто забивает нулями всю выделенную память

Comment: @Komdosh домножает каждый байт на ноль :)

Comment: @Komdosh Имеется в виду, что у `calloc` два аргумента, и итоговый размер получается их перемножением, видимо.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat да, это и имел ввиду. Не знал что `calloc` затирает нулями. Спасибо большое!

Comment: ну это да, но кстати не всё тут может оказаться правдой из-за особенностей ОС, одни могут например по тупому копировать при realloc, другие проверять есть ли свободная память и довыделять, но если её не будет хватать, то выделять в новом месте.